# I can't decrypt the files

Tags: python, encryption

```
import os
import pyAesCrypt

def decryption (file, password):
    buffer_size = 512 * 1024
    pyAesCrypt.decryptFile(
        str(file),
        str(os.path.splitext(file)[0]) + ".crp", password, buffer_size)

print ("[File '" + str(os. path. splitext(file)[0]) + "' decryptor]")

os.remove(file)

def walking_by_dirs(dir, password):

for name in os.listdir(dir):
path = os.path.join (dir, name)


if os.path.idfile(path):
    try:
        decryption(path, password)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

else:
    walking_by_dirs(path, password)


password = input ("Enter the decryption password:")
walking_by_dirs(r"C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\New folder", password)
```

---

The error:

> PS C:\Users\Админ\Desktop\расширения\шифрования> & C:/Users/Админ/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Админ/Desktop/расширения/шифрования/decryption.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\Админ\Desktop\расширения\шифрования\decryption.py", line 1, in 
> from _typeshed import FileDescriptor
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_typeshed'

Comment: The error message suggests the problem is in the python environment - it cannot find _typeshed when importing os.  Does this work:?

"import os"  (Line 1)
"print (os.listdir())" (Line 2)

If not, you need to reinstall python or use a configured sety-up like Ananconda python

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not provide the whole code...

The error `from _typeshed import FileDescriptor` is clear enough. You are using the `_typeshed` package in the file `decryption.py` but typeshed is not installed.

You can install it with this command:

```
pip install types-six types-requests
```